# How to show on JSF site on browser address bar for all pages just the index page?

Tags: jsf, single-page-application

I wonder how can I make in a web project made in JSF with primefaces or even without primefaces, to appear in browser just the index page, for example all the time I am on that site to appear mysite.com/ABC/index.xhtml don't matter on what page I am navigating on that web Site.

Thank you,
Vlad.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: for example when I am writing on here  <p:menuitem value="External" action="page2" /> in the addres bar to be index.xhtml and not page2.xhtml and when I am going from a here <p:commandLink  action="anf.xhtml"> to be the same in address bar just index.xhtml and not anf.xhtml